# Same document being returned twice when querying from Lucene Index

Tags: lucene

I'm new to Lucene. I have some news texts which I am indexing using the fields below:

```
doc.add(new Field("url", article.getUrl(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("source", article.getSource(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("title", article.getArticleTitle(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("content", article.getArticleContent(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("date", DateTools.dateToString(article.getArticleDate(), DateTools.Resolution.DAY), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
doc.add(new Field("type", article.getType().getName(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
```

When I do a query basing on these fields, in some instances, the same document is being returned twice. I query the index using the following code:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);

String contentQueryString = buildQuery(contentKeywords);
Query contentKeywordsQuery = null;
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(contentQueryString)) {
    contentKeywordsQuery = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "content", analyzer).parse(contentQueryString);
}

Query titleKeywordsQuery = null;
String titleQueryString = buildQuery(titleKeywords);
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(titleQueryString)) {
    titleKeywordsQuery = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, "title", analyzer).parse(titleQueryString);
}

String sFrom = DateTools.dateToString(from, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
String sTo = DateTools.dateToString(to, DateTools.Resolution.DAY);
Term lowerTerm = new Term("date", sFrom);
Term upperTerm = new Term("date", sTo);
Query dateQuery = new TermRangeQuery("date", lowerTerm.bytes(), upperTerm.bytes(), true, true);

Term sourceTerm = new Term("source", source);
Query sourceQuery = new TermQuery(sourceTerm);

Term typeTerm = new Term("type", type);
Query typeQuery = new TermQuery(typeTerm);

BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
q.add(dateQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
q.add(sourceQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
q.add(typeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
if (null != titleKeywordsQuery) {
    q.add(titleKeywordsQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
if (null != contentKeywordsQuery) {
    q.add(contentKeywordsQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
Directory index = new SimpleFSDirectory(new File("resources/lucene_index"));
int hitsPerPage = 5;
IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
searcher.search(q, collector);
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    QueryResult r = new QueryResult(d.get("url"), d.get("title"), d.get("date"), hits[i].score);
    results.add(r);
}
```

This line in particular is giving two hits for the same document:

```
ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

There shouldn't be any duplicate documents in the index, I've checked it out.

Comment: could you please show us the query as well

Comment: I've added the query. In the code a method buildQuery() is used. The method creates an OR query using text passed to it. Sample output of the method would be "Thursday OR May" given Thursday, May

Comment: You probably added the same document twice, can you paste the indexing code as well?

Comment: Have you confirmed (through debugging) that hits contains entries (say, at index1 and index2) such that hits[index1].doc == hits[index2].doc?  (Note: I am not asking about the contents of the document, but the Lucene document id)

Comment: I found the problem. Indeed some of the documents were being indexed twice because some news articles had been retrieved twice. 10x for your help guys!